# Angular 4 test D3 zoom

Tags: angular, unit-testing, d3.js

I am trying to test that the zooming feature in my D3 V4 scale works.

So far I have:

```
it('should zoom', async(() => {
   spyOn(component, 'zoomed');

   component.setDates(data1);
   component.grapher()

   let svg = d3.select('svg')

   //code to trigger zooming on svg goes here

   fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
     expect(component.zoomed).toHaveBeenCalled();
   })
}));
```

Where `zoomed` is the method I have defined to be triggered when zooming, `grapher()` is the method that creates the svg graph, and `data1` is an array of dates that will make my scale.

**Thank you for your time!**

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but i came across a similar problem and i found a solution that might help you.

Since **d3-zoom** does not use Angular event binding your are not able to create mouse events that emulate zooming in unit tests by calling [`DebugElement.triggerEventHandler()`](https://angular.io/api/core/DebugElement#triggereventhandler).

Native event binding has to be used instead.

Example:

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#my-svg')).nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('dblclick', {
  clientX: 692,
  clientY: 350
} as MouseEvent));
```

This simulates a double click event onto a svg that has the id `my-svg`. This should trigger a registered **d3-zoom** listener. To simulate other means of zooming, wheel or mouse move events can be used.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this